# windows phone - textbox background

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, textbox

I have `Textbox` with blue `Background` and white `Foreground`. When entering a text my whole `Textbox` becomes white and i cannot see what i am typing because im writing white letters on white background. How to change background of a textbox when writing to i.e. blue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the `GotFocus` event handler to the TextBox like this.

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }
```

Comment: Excelent, this problem came to me while selecting a light theme for the phone environment

Answer (score 4):

A much better way to do this is to directly edit the focused style in expression blend. This tutorial will help you out.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-textbox-light-theme-problems-the-solution